# What type of regex does Google Colab use for find and replace feature

Tags: regex, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use a Regular Expression in the Find and Replace feature within Google Colab, located in the left side tool bar, but it does not seem to recognize it. Is there a specific Regular expression that Google Colaboratory uses?

I'm trying to find фll occurrences of `xtst` excluding occurrences `xtst_`, `xtst2_`.

Expression I've tried:

- `xtst(?!\_+|\d+)`
- `(xtst(?!\_+|\d+))`
- `(xtst)(?!\_+|\d+)`
- `r"(xtst(?!\_+|\d+))"`

This string works, but is incorrect as it's looking for all occurrences of `x`,`t`,`s`,`t` everywhere.

- `[xtst](?!\_+|\d+)`

---

Test string:

- `xtr, xtst, ytr, ytst =`

Result of working RE for the string above would be:

- `xtst`

The 1st RE is working fine at regex101.com as well as the 2nd, and 3rd RE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not escape the underscore `_`, it is a word character, and escaping word characters is not always allowed across regex libraries.

What you want to match is `xtst` not followed with either a digit or underscore, so you can use

```py
xtst(?!_|\d)
xtst(?![\d_])
xtst(?![0-9_])
```